how to draw semicircle (half circle) in flutter
I have this code that has semicircle and is fine , but i want it to be upside down , just like only flip the curve to be U shape:
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 7,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: TopSemicircleClipper(),
          child: Container(
            color: const Color(0xFF09BAB5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


   class TopSemicircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
   Path getClip(Size size) {
var path = Path();
path.lineTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

path.arcToPoint(
  Offset(0, size.height),
  radius: Radius.elliptical(size.width, size.height),
  clockwise: false,
);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
path.close();
return path;
}

    @override
   bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
  }

which is like this :

but i want semicircle to be like this :

i mean i want to flip the semicircle

If you set clockwise to true , the semi circle should be flipped. You will have to play around the x and y values of the ellipse to get that effect in reference. Good luck!

can you please give a code how to do that , i have tried but didnt get the result i want , thanks @ClevinoAlrin

We don't need to complicate things; simply apply a borderRadius to a container.
Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height : 400,
          width : 300,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
               bottomLeft: Radius.circular(270),
               bottomRight: Radius.circular(200)),
           color: Color(0xFF09BAB5)),
        ),
      ),



@behnam You can use stack and put the white color in scaffold background and then create a green container similar to above code for your solution.
